# 3ware 9650SE-2LP "sync" after a drive failure

Tags: raid, hardware-raid, raid1, data-recovery, 3ware

I have a 3ware 9650SE-2LP card that was set up to mirror two 1 TB disks (let's call them Disk A and Disk B).  A couple of months or so ago the array stopped working (gave me an error at boot-up saying that there was something wrong -- unfortunately, I didn't write down exact error message).  Curious, I took the 3ware card out, unplugged Disk A from it and plugged it directly into the SATA port on my computer's motherboard and it worked fine.  Since I had a project that I needed to get out, I used Disk A (without mirroring) just plugged directly into my motherboard. I figured that Disk B died on me.

Fast forward to yesterday.  Project being (mostly) done, I decided to investigate the non-working mirror.  I unplugged Disk A from the motherboard and plugged in Disk B to make an astonishing discovery that Disk B works!  It has the state from when I unplugged the 3ware card a couple of months ago.  The problem was the SATA cable that was attached to Disk B (first time I've had a cable fail on me!).

I've replaced the cable.  Now I would like to bring the mirror back.  Is there any way to do it without destroying what is on Disk A?  Basically, is there a way to have the card replicate Disk A on Disk B bit-by-bit and rebuild the mirror that way?  I couldn't immediately find such option in the 3ware BIOS utility.  Basically, it just gives me the option to select the two drives, and create a unit (it doesn't seem to remember that I used to have these two drives in a mirror before). While I could back up the Disk A and rebuild this mirror by wiping both disks, I would like to avoid that if I can (I have back up of the most important stuff, but I don't have a spare 1 TB disk that I could use to dump all the stuff on Drive A to).

I apologize if this question is dumb, I am kind of new to this and thought that this would be an appropriate community to ask as I saw multiple discussion on the 3ware cards here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have used DiskA outside the array DiskA will be deprecated, so in a best case scenario DiskB will be recognized as part of an array and you can assign DiskA as a spare. In this case your data will be cloned from DiskB to DiskA. But that's not really what you want. So, in order to recreate your mirror, you have to assign both drives into a new 3Ware raid array, which means, your data will be destroyed. There is no clone option for 3Ware 9650, but you can write to LSI support (they have bought 3Ware).